# cursor doesn't point to the center of textbox in mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox

Cursor doesn't point to the center of textbox.it aligns to left top in Firefox.

Any idea?

Comment: Idea without any code or example? I don't think so..

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say here. When your focus moves into an empty text box, doesn't it always start at the top left because, you know, that's how text alignment works? Please elaborate on what you mean here.

Comment: <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="inputbox" onKeyUp="changeval();" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />

Comment: css for this is.inputbox {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0 0;
border:1px solid #9B9BAA;
font-size:15px;
height:51px;
width:369px;
margin-top:4px;
text-align: default;}

Comment: here cursor aligns to top left..i need it to be left center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me with Firefox 4. It seems to have been fixed by [bug 481741](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=481741).